# Based on the output, what is computed value for r?

Tags: self-study, correlation, spss, pearson-r, psychology

[image]

(What is the value exactly as it appears on the output with no spaces between characters.)?

Pearson's correlation coefficient is r.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your image, the correlation between Weight and Income is $-0.931$. Note that the same number occurs in two lines:

- when row is Weight and column is Income
- when row is Income and column is Weight

which are the off-diagonal entries of a 2x2 correlation matrix.

Comment: Is the downvote because of something wrong in the answer, or something not right about answering the question in the first place?

Comment: I see upvote, I don't see downvote.